# Table missing in a database but query works

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-table

I have a table `TBLT_GLDET` in my SQL Server 2008 database. When I open a new query window and select the right database and execute following query

```
select * 
from TBLT_GLDET;
```

the data appears. But in the tables list the table does not appear.

Also when I try to open the table for a Crystal Report using database expert in Visual Studio, it says the table is missing in the database.

What is the reason for this?

[image]

I did following things. I double checked whether it's the right database.
I refreshed the database.

Comment: maybe there's a `synonym` or `view` with the same name.

Comment: Maybe you haven't refreshed the object explorer in awhile. I bet `SELECT * FROM sys.objects where [name] = 'TBLT_GLDET';`returns something. (Provided you're connected to the right database).

Comment: You can also use ALT + F1 (after selecting the name) in SSMS to know more about the object and its type.

Comment: just refresh your database